# Rendering dynamically generated image to Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, httpresponse

I've been searching for this and have tried to implement several solutions in other answers, but have had no success doing this.

I am **successfully getting an HTTPResponse** for the image using the following approach:

```
frontier_plot_data = Image.open("plot.png")
# serialize to HTTP response
frontier_plot = imgResponse(frontier_plot_data)
return(frontier_plot)
```

The function for imgResponse:

```
def imgResponse(valid_image):
    try:
        with open(valid_image, "rb") as f:
            return HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="image/jpeg")
    except:
        red = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (255,0,0,0))
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
        red.save(response, "JPEG")
        return response
```

I return `frontier_plot` to my `views.py` and pass it into the context:

```
context = {"form": form, "frontier_plot": frontier_plot}
```

I then try to render it in my `template` HTML file with this line, which I've been using for regular HTML strings:

```
{{ frontier_plot }}
```

This is not a static image, but rather one that is generated then saved by a process. It is just always overwritten to `plot.png`.

I've read some things about using URL references and the Django render function, but I'm not sure of the implementation.

I don't think I can create a separate view just to view this plot because although I have simplified it for this question, there are actually multiple returned plots from this process.

Comment: If it's an image you should render it in an image tag, no? `<img src="{% static_url/media_url/wherever you access your image from %}/path/to/your/plot.png" />`

Comment: @limelights Do you mind elaborating a bit? The image isn't static as it's generated dynamically within a process in the view.

Comment: Doesnt matter if you generate it. It's still an image that you need to render with an image tag. Serve it as a normal image. Take a look at how to serve static files in Django.